# Firebase files in tableview along with folders

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning **Firebase** with my project. In my app I have set up a `tableView` which shows all the filenames that users have been uploading to `database`. I would like to add such functionality that along those files would be folders which could hold other files (not yet listed in `tableView`). Is there a way to make `tableView` recognize files as files and folders as folders?

Here is data structure in `Firebase`: Firebase structure

[image]

Comment: So you want to get testFolder etc... from your Firebase Structure ? I don't understant what you really want ?

Comment: I have tableView with files stored under users/{uid}/profile/urls/{url}. I would like to also list folders in tableView (which is not a problem itself) but how can i force tableView to know which cell i can open(file) or get new tableView with files from folder? I want it to be similar to Dropbox where you have a list of files along with different folders.

Comment: Maybe put a flag isFile or not is a folder. Respect a naming pattern like calling all the files with the prefix file or others with folder...Or in general, if you reach a file there is no children below them. On the contrary, with folders you have children with files below or other folders no ?

Comment: I was thinking about "no children" way. In case of a flag, how could i implement it?

Comment: You can add an attribute in your Firebase Structure called 'isFile" below each file node and folder node and set it to true if it's a file or false if not.

Comment: Okay, but in terms of tableView, how can i differentiate the behaviour of cells if it should open a file or present new tableView?

Comment: As you get the information flag based on te cell content. In a function called didSelectRow I think you can implement the desired behavior if it's a file or not.